# ng16 Upgrade from ng15: Type '(event: RouterEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: Event_2) => void'

Tags: angular, typescript

After upgrading my Angular project from ng15 to ng16, I am getting errors on the code below. Any insights into what is wrong with this event argument the way its constructed?

```
if (this.menuOpenSubscription === undefined) {
   this.menuOpenSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe(
    (event: RouterEvent) => this.handleNavigationEnd(event)); // Error in ng16
}
```

Errors on compile:

```
> Overload 1 of 2, '(observerOrNext?: Partial<Observer<Event_2>> |
> ((value: Event_2) => void)): Subscription', gave the following error.
> [1]     Argument of type '(event: RouterEvent) => void' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Observer<Event_2>> | ((value:
> Event_2) => void)'. [1]       Type '(event: RouterEvent) => void' is
> not assignable to type '(value: Event_2) => void'. [1]         Types
> of parameters 'event' and 'value' are incompatible. [1]           Type
> 'Event_2' is not assignable to type 'RouterEvent'. [1]            
> Type 'ActivationEnd' is missing the following properties from type
> 'RouterEvent': id, url [1]   Overload 2 of 2, '(next?: (value:
> Event_2) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () =>
> void): Subscription', gave the following error. [1]     Argument of
> type '(event: RouterEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of
> type '(value: Event_2) => void'. [1]       Types of parameters 'event'
> and 'value' are incompatible. [1]         Type 'Event_2' is not
> assignable to type 'RouterEvent'.
```

Comment: Can you also include the contents of `handleNavigationEnd`?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Event` from `@angular/router` to resolve this issue, please find below a working example!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import {
  Router,
  Event,
  NavigationEnd,
  provideRouter,
  RouterModule,
} from '@angular/router';
import 'zone.js';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a routerLink="test">
      go to route
    </a>
    <router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  menuOpenSubscription!: Subscription;
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    if (this.menuOpenSubscription === undefined) {
      this.menuOpenSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) =>
        this.handleNavigationEnd(event)
      ); // Error in ng16
    }
  }

  handleNavigationEnd(e: Event) {
    if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      console.log('navigation end');
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      {
        path: 'test',
        component: TestComponent,
      },
    ]),
  ],
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7i7xju?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)